# Showing that $D= \{f \in C([0,1])| f(x) \geq 0 \} $ is a closed set

Tags: real-analysis

Let $B= \{f \in C([0,1])| f(x) > 0  $ for all $x \in [0,1] \}$. I am trying to find the closure of $B$ equipped with the sup norm.

My textbook states:

Let $D= \{f \in C([0,1])| f(x) \geq 0 \} $.

"This is a closed set because if $f_n(x) \geq 0$, and $f_n \rightarrow f$ uniformly, and hence pointwise, then $f(x) \geq 0$ for all $x$ ".

This seems intuitive, but I am not sure why this is true. Somehow I have to connect the ideas that for arbitrary $\epsilon>0$, any $x \in [0,1]$ that there exists $n \in \Bbb N$ with 
$\{ sup\{d(f_n(x), f), x\in A\} < \epsilon \}$ and also that $f_n(x) \geq 0$, so if $f(x) < 0$ then I would derive a contradiction. Not sure how to complete this thought. This would show that $D \subset cl(B)$.

After having shown that it states...

"To show $D$ is the closure it suffices to show that for $f \in D$, there is an $f_n \in B$ such that $f_n \rightarrow f$ ".

I am not sure why this is the next step because I thought we already showed that $D \subset cl(B)$ and now I should show that $cl(B) \subset D$. Any insights appreciated.

Comment: @Surb the first one, will edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need two facts.

Uniform convergence implies pointwise convergence: if $x\in [0,1]$, let $\epsilon>0$. Let $n_0>0$ be such that $\|f_n-f\|<\epsilon$ for $n>n_0$. Then, for $n>n_0$ you get $$|f_n(x)-f(x)|\leq \|f_n-f\|<\epsilon, $$and we conclude that the numerical sequence $(f_n(x))_{n\geq 0}$ converges to $f(x)$.

The limit of a non-negative sequence is non-negative: assume $(a_n)_{n\geq 0}$ is a sequence such that $a_n\geq 0$ for $n\geq n_+$, and $a_n\to L$. If $a_n=0$ for all $n\geq n_0$, done. Otherwise you can assume that $a_{n_+}>0$, by replacing $n_+$ with the first index $n^*\geq n_0$ such that $a_{n^*}>0$, if needed. Given $\epsilon = a_{n_+}$, take the corresponding $n_0$. You can assume that $n_0\geq n_+$, replacing $n_0$ by $\max\{n_0,n_+\}$ if needed. Then $$|a_{n_+}-L|\leq a_{n_+}\implies L \geq 0$$as wanted.

Also, the second step follows because $D$ is closed, so $B\subseteq D$ implies  ${\rm cl}(B)\subseteq D$.

Comment: Right the limit of a non-negative sequence that converges is non-negative. I should have remembered that. Thanks for the help!